# mysql join : i dont get rows with no corispondent in the left table , even when i use left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have 2 tables

1 - coupons

2 - tractions

for each coupon there might be couple of rows in tractions table 
i want to have list of all coupons and count of it's tractions (void ones in this example)

```
SELECT `coupons`.*, count(tractions_void.id) as void 

FROM `coupons` 
    LEFT JOIN `tractions` AS `tractions_void` 

ON `tractions_void`.`coupon_parent` = `coupons`.`id` 
    AND `tractions_void`.`expired`  = 1

WHERE `coupons`.`parent` =0
```

the problem is even though i use left  join , in the output i only get coupons with at least 1 tractions .... basically i dont get the coupons with 0 tractions in the query result at all

i want to have them with 0 as `tractions_void` ... i thought if i use left join i wont have this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT c.*, count(t.id) as void
FROM coupons c LEFT JOIN 
     tractions t 
     ON t.coupon_parent = c.id AND
        t.expired  = 1
WHERE c.parent = 0
group by c.id;
```

I also replaced the table names with shorter aliases and removed the backticks to make the query more readable.

Your original query only returned one row, because it had an aggregation function in the `select` clause and no `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 SELECT `coupons`.*, count(tractions_void.id) as void 

 FROM `coupons` 
 LEFT JOIN `tractions` AS `tractions_void` 

 ON `tractions_void`.`coupon_parent` = `coupons`.`id` 


WHERE `coupons`.`parent` =0  
AND `tractions_void`.`expired`  = 1
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----moved this here in where clause
```